# Android read values from constants xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I am having my own `constants.xml` file like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="dialog_fragment_height">7</integer>
    <integer name="dialog_fragment_width">8</integer>
</resources>
```

Now I need to read this values in Java file and use it as window parameters  -

```
 DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int width = dm.widthPixels;
        int height = dm.heightPixels;
        getWindow().setLayout((int)(width * //read here width ),(int)(height * //read here height));
```

How doI do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract it using these code:

int width = getContext().getResources().getInteger(R.integer.dialog_fragment_height);

Answer (score 1):

Also you can store value in dp, like

```
<dimen name="width">200dp</dimen>
```

and get it

```
getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.width);
```

or if you need get just integer value from your xml file, then use

```
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.myint)
```